What do some values of __cplusplus mean?
I've set -std=c++23 in tasks.json but for some reason, std::cout << __cplusplus prints 202100 instead of 202300.
Why so?

Are you certain your compiler supports C++23?

For g++ --version it gives
g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0 Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

IIRC compilers typically only set the new, higher value once they have complete or reasonably complete support for the specific version. The GCC support for 23 is still incomplete. You can use the feature test macros to find out which parts specifically are supported

Why so? Your compiler is too old to support C++23.  Or vice versa, C++23 is too new, and your compiler doesn't support it yet.
